# Image-rendering logic troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app where I populate a dropdown with folder names from an backend. When a folder is selected in the dropdown  the images in that folder gets rendered in the react app. All works as expected but when looking at the developer tools in chrome I see alot of errors when changing values in the dropdown .

If I have this folders:

```
  folder1       folder2
    -A.jpg        -X.jpg
    -B.jpg        -Y.jpg
```

On load **folder1** is selected as default and images are rendered correct and no error-messages. The url that gets passed to the img elements is:

```
http://localhost:8080/images/folder1/A.jpg
http://localhost:8080/images/folder1/B.jpg
```

But when I change to **folder2** new images shows correctly but when looking at the console it also tries to render the previous images but with the new foldername:

```
http://localhost:8080/images/folder2/X.jpg 
http://localhost:8080/images/folder2/Y.jpg 
http://localhost:8080/images/folder2/A.jpg *error
http://localhost:8080/images/folder2/B.jpg *error
```

To me it looks like the old img elements needs to be removed before adding the new elements, is this correct or what do I need to do to fix this?

***image-gallery.component.jsx***

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Image } from './image.component'
import './image-gallery.styles.scss'

export const ImageGallery = ({theme}) => {
    const [imageNames, setImageNames] = useState()
    const fileListUrl = `http://localhost:8080/api/folders/${theme}`
    const baseUrl = `http://localhost:8080/images/${theme}/`

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchFileNames = async () => {
            const data = await fetch(fileListUrl)
            const files = await data.json()
            setImageNames(files)
        }
        fetchFileNames()
    }, [fileListUrl,theme])

    return (
        <div className="gallery-container">
           {imageNames && imageNames.map(imageName => <Image key={imageName} imageName={imageName} imageUrl={baseUrl+imageName}/>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

***image.component.jsx***

```
import React from 'react'
import './image-gallery.styles.scss'

export const Image = ({imageUrl, imageName}) => {
    return (
        <div className="image-wrapper">
            <img className="image" alt={imageName} src={imageUrl} height="200px" width="300px"/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

combo-box

```
import React from 'react'

export const ComboBox = ({title, themes, setTheme, onSelect}) => {


    return (
        <div className="form-group">
        <label className="label" htmlFor="select1">
          {title}
        </label>
        <div className="flex-line">
          <div className="flex-group">
            <select className="form-select" id="select1" onChange={(e)=> setTheme(e.target.value)} >
            {themes.map(theme => <option key={theme}>{theme}</option>)}
            </select>
          </div>
          <button className="button-icon" onClick={onSelect} >
            <i className="material-icons">check</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

StartPage

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ComboBox } from "./admin-components/combo-box.component";
import { ImageGallery } from "./image-component/image-gallery.component";
import "./admin.styles.scss";
import { FileUpload } from "./file-upload-component/file-upload.component";

export const AdminPage = ({ themes }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  const [showGallery, setShowGallery] = useState(true);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    themes && setSelected(themes[0]);
  }, [themes]);

  const onSelect = () => {
    setShowGallery(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="admin-container">
      <header></header>
      <main>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="layout-group-sub">
            <h3>Välj Bilder</h3>
            <p className="introduction">
              info...
            </p>
            {themes && (
              <ComboBox
                themes={themes}
                title={"Välj tema"}
                setTheme={setSelected}
                onSelect={onSelect}
              />
            )}
            <div className="button-container">
              <button
                className="button-sub"
                onClick={() => setShowGallery(false)}
              >
                Skapa Nytt
              </button>
              {!showGallery && (
                <>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="new-theme-input"
                    value={input}
                    onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                  />
                  <FileUpload files={selectedFiles} setFiles={setSelectedFiles} />
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          {showGallery && <ImageGallery theme={selected} />}
        </div>
              {selectedFiles.length > 0 && selectedFiles.map(file => <p>{file.id +" "+file.name}</p>)}
      </main>
      <footer> </footer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: It would help to add the code of the component that you're using the `ImageGallery` component so to see how you pass the `theme` prop. Also, you don't have to add `fileListUrl` to the effect of the `theme` prop.

Comment: Ok, I did not want to clutter with information. The "theme"-prop is just a string like "folder1" or "folder2"

Comment: I know what `theme` prop does and what values it does get, that's quite obvious; what it's not obvious, is that maybe there is an issue on how that prop is passed when the folder is changed in the dropdown box. Did you try to log the result of `files` and the value `imageNames` on each render?

Comment: both `files` and `imageNames` contain the right values but I think it is:
`{imageNames && imageNames.map(imageName => <Image key={imageName} imageName={imageName} imageUrl={baseUrl+imageName}/>)} `
thats causing the issue. As the `baseUrl` changes and the previous `img` elements still remains but gets hidden on each change and gets a new updated `baseUrl` that dos not match the current folder

Comment: The previous image elements do get cleared when you do `setImageNames(files)`. If `imageNames` contains the correct items, then there is nothing wrong with the map `Image` render. I suspect the issue is on how you're using `ImageGallery` component on dropdown change.

Comment: Ok, I added more code in the main post

Comment: Please check my answer and try to use `useLayoutEffect` to clean the `imageNames` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass the `theme` for second time with the `folder2` value, the render code gets to execute before the `theme` effect executes moreover that it has a promise to resolve inside, thus render executes 2 times, one with the previous values and one with the new values but both with `theme = 'folder2'`. <del>To overcome this issue, you'll have to use [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) to clear the `imageNames` array. Doing so, there won't be a render with the previous values but with an empty array for the second render.</del> Apparently there is a render occurring before `useLayoutEffect`, so to overcome this issue you can just setup a state variable to check if the current theme is equal to the selected theme; if it isn't you don't render the images, else if it is then render them; you'll set it to the `theme` after the image files are fetched and set:

```jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
...

export const ImageGallery = ({theme}) => {
    const [imageNames, setImageNames] = useState([])
    // Set a state variable to hold the current theme used
    const [currentTheme, setCurrentTheme] = useState(theme)

    const fileListUrl = `http://localhost:8080/api/folders/${theme}`
    const baseUrl = `http://localhost:8080/images/${theme}/`

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchFileNames = async () => {
            const data = await fetch(fileListUrl)
            const files = await data.json()
            setImageNames(files)
            // Set current theme used
            setCurrentTheme(theme)
        }
        fetchFileNames()
    }, [theme])

    // Render images only if the current theme is equal to the selected theme
    return (
        <div className="gallery-container">
           {currentTheme === theme && imageNames && imageNames.map(imageName => <Image key={imageName} imageName={imageName} imageUrl={baseUrl+imageName}/>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested the code but the result is the same.

Comment: Yes, `useLayoutEffect` didn't prevent the render to happen before it clears the images. You can set a variable to check the current theme against the selected theme, check my updated answer.

Comment: Ah, thank you for all the help. Everything works now.